# Is this AC circuit wired correctly?

Tags: ac, relay

Is the following AC cicruit wired correctly? And is it safe to plug in if i use electrical tape to cover the open connections?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a terminal block or something sane?

Comment: It’s temporary just to test it with the Arduino

Comment: Is this a duplicate question?  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24576/how-to-hook-up-a-mains-voltage-relay

Comment: Someone will touch a live wire very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be correct assuming green is ground blue is neutral and brown is hot. I can't verify is you have selected the appropriate relay contact connections. I also can not verify if the relay is appropriate for the load. If you tape the connections, it will be marginally safe, but not reliable. and thus not safe for continued use. Nothing that is home made is really acceptable to leave connected without the maker present.

Answer (score 3):

Twisting wires together is not safe. Use splice block connectors or wire nuts.

Unless the wires are fixed in place, you will also need strain relief to prevent strands from breaking and falling into the device causing a short.

Comment: After doing that is the AC wire safe to plug in?

Comment: If you're going to be doing this sort of work, a [small set of assorted wire nuts](https://www.amazon.com/Gardner-Bender-25-AWC-Assortment-Electrical/dp/B000F5TTE8/ref=asc_df_B000F5TTE8/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=216516247812&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14875431659104534464&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001928&hvtargid=pla-373916419594&psc=1) would be a cheap investment for a lot of safety.

Answer (score 3):

Twisting the wires together like that does not create a secure connection. Instead use proper terminal block. One set of wires is crimped but the other is not, having both sides crimped when going into terminals is preferred. If neither side is crimped you could solder the wires together instead.

Singular strands of the wires may poke through electrical tape.

There a bit too much exposed copper on the relay connection. There is a real danger of the connection flexing bridging over to the other wire.

There is no strain relief.

I would expect you to put this in a project box and guide the wires into it and make sure no inquiring fingers can reach the live parts. If the project box is metal you must connect the ground wires (yellow/green wires) to the enclosure and insert a sheet of plastic between the backside of the any board and the enclosure.

Comment: Also, I can't see the "stranded wire to crimped sleeve of another wire" contact being any good there; a wire to wire one would've been better imo.

Answer (score 0):

Even for testing I would suggest you to take MCB(Circuit breaker) So that you will get some control over the connection. You can turn off the MCB if you feel something went wrong.